# NetSuite UserEvent SuiteScript 2.0 not firing on Support Case Create

Tags: netsuite, userscripts, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Have a UserEvent SuiteScript 2.0 which is only firing when the create Support Case is performed in the UI and not when the case is created via Email submission.

```
/**
 * Support Case Users Scripts
 *
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @ModuleScope SameAccount
 *
 */
define(["N/log"], function (log) {
    var exports = {};
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    function beforeSubmit(context) {
        log.debug('before submitting', 'in');
    }
    exports.beforeSubmit = beforeSubmit;
    return exports;
});
```

Have tried `beforeLoad` & `afterSubmit` as well, in addition `ModuleScope` tried `Public`. Script deployment has all 27 context selected. I see my log in all cases when via the UI. Was also having trouble with getting a workflow to fire during the same event. I have a script which does fire using SuiteScript 1 just fine and so I could extend this one, though I'd prefer to continue working in 2.0.

Comment: A common reason is forgetting Status: Testing on a deployment means it only runs for you and the specified audience as long as you are a member of that audience type.

Comment: Thanks, that was totally it! Knew it was likely something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When submitting a *Support Case* via Email, *Script Deployment* `Status` needs to be set to `Released` for the script to trigger.

Comment: I know this is old, but do you have any ideas why it would still not work when it's set to Released, all roles, all employees, and run as admin? It triggers when saving any case just not when it comes through email. At my last job I had a script working just fine that triggered on an email to a case profile, but for some reason I can't figure it out in this instance.

Comment: Well more context is needed most likely to answer this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was an error caused by another script, so the new user event I wrote never executed. Our environment is a mess and we don't have emails turned on in Sandbox, so it wasn't obvious at first.